# By selecting item in spinner the new activity is opened

Tags: android, android-activity, android-spinner

I am developing an android app where, while registering, the user can select a type, either "individual" or "company". When he chooses company, a new activity is opened where he can enter information about the company. Please help me how to navigate to new activity. I tried but didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `setOnItemSelectedListener`,if select something `onItemSelected` is called ,else `onNothingSelected` is called

```
 s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                 String str = (String) arg0.getSelectedItem();

                             //here print selected value...
                 System.out.println("String is :: " + str);

                             //And StartActivity here...

                    Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks it gave me enough idea.:)

Answer (score 0):

Implement listener to spinner, then check for clicked position, if it's the company one open a new Activity using intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondClass.class);
startAtivity(i);
```